# Why does adding a SUM(column) throw a group by error [SQL]

Tags: sql, mariadb

I found some similar questions, but none of the solutions would work, nor did they explain what was causing the issue.

I have a working query

```
SELECT pages.pageString pageName, timeSpent
FROM
     (SELECT `page_id`, SUM(`time_spent`) as timeSpent
      FROM `pageViews` 
      WHERE `time_spent` > 0 
      GROUP BY `page_id`) myTable
JOIN pages ON pages.id = page_id 
ORDER BY timeSpent DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

This returns results that look like

```
+------------------------------+-----------+
| pageName                     | timeSpent |
+------------------------------+-----------+
| page 1                       |    394292 |
| page 2                       |     66990 |
| page 3                       |     53896 |
| page 4                       |     37796 |
| page 5                       |     14982 |
+------------------------------+-----------+
```

I'd like to add a column containing the percentage of timeSpent relative to the other pages, to start I added a SUM(timeSpent) to my query but that throws an error

```
In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'pages.pageString'
```

Im not sure why this column is effected by adding this new column to the select statement.

Sadly any solution involving changing sql settings won't work due to company policy.
I appreciate any advice

UPDATE

The failing sql statement is

```
SELECT pages.pageString pageName, timeSpent FROM
  (SELECT `page_id`, SUM(`time_spent`) as timeSpent FROM
     `pageViews` WHERE `time_spent` > 0 GROUP BY `page_id`) myTable
  JOIN pages ON pages.id = page_id ORDER BY timeSpent DESC LIMIT 5
```

As per the first answer I added a groupBy which solves the error

```
SELECT pages.pageString pageName, timeSpent, SUM(timeSpent) FROM
    (SELECT `page_id`, SUM(`time_spent`) as timeSpent FROM `pageViews` WHERE `time_spent` > 0 GROUP BY `page_id`) myTable
 JOIN pages ON pages.id = page_id GROUP BY pageName ORDER BY timeSpent DESC LIMIT 5
```

This however does not give the proper output

```
+------------------------------+-----------+----------------+
| pageName                     | timeSpent | SUM(timeSpent) |
+------------------------------+-----------+----------------+
| page 1.                      |    390210 |         390210 |
| page 2                       |     66972 |          66972 |
| page3                        |     52332 |          52332 |
| page4                        |     25454 |          25454 |
| page5                        |     13552 |          13552 |
+------------------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Ideally this SUM(timeSpent) would be 390210+ 66972 + 52332 + 25454 + 13552 so that I may do timeSpent / SUM(timeSpent)

Comment: Starting v10.2 MariaDB supports window functions. What is your version?

Comment: `I'd like to add a row containing the percentage` - did you mean column by chance? Otherwise please try to be clearer, I do not seem to understand and other might have difficulties too then.

Comment: Yes I meant column @Ely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say where you tried to put the `sum(timeSpent)` but I believe one can try to reconstruct with the error message:

```
In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'pages.pageString'
```

It says what the problem is. You added `sum(timeSpent)` to the projection, but the SQL statement does not have a GROUP BY, in particular it mentions the first item which should be aggregated  `pages.pageString`.

It would mention the other ones too, once you fix this one.

On the other hand, please make sure you post exactly the failing SQL statement instead of trying to describe how to get the error you have. It's better for us who try to help.

### Update:

You have two tables/views `pages` and `pageViews`. The first one is used to get the page name. I would  just focus on the time calculation to make things easier. Figuring out the name afterwards is simple, because it is directly connected to the `page_id`.

1. The first information you want is the sum of all times spent so that you can calculate the ratio to this sum.
   This is simply an aggregation where you sum the times over all pages.
2. The second information you want is the sum of the times per `page_id`. You already know how to do that. You group by the `page_id` while aggregating the sums of each.
3. Try to put those two together now. You have the first statement of which the result shall be applied to each row of the second statement so that you get the table form `page_id, time_spent_page, time_spent_all`.
4. When you have step 3 then it is easy to add the `page_name` now, since you have the `page_id` which is required for a simple join.

I tried no to give away the solution. Maybe you like to try again following the steps above. If you have difficulties, simply leave a comment (maybe showing how far you got).

It might look complex in the beginning, but once you have done that successfully I hope you'll see that it can be simple.

Comment: I have updated the original post

Comment: I have added a possible solution outline. I believe I have understood your problem statement. Otherwise let us know where I went wrong.

Comment: Thanks using the guide I was able to complete the query, and I realized that my production and development environments are different, on dev we run MariaDB that supports window function, on prod its mysql 5.7 which does not

Answer (score 0):

Adding a column containing the percentage of timeSpent relative to the sum of all pages

```
SELECT pages.pageString pageName, timeSpent,
  , timeSpent / sum(timeSpent) over() * 100 p
FROM
     (SELECT `page_id`, SUM(`time_spent`) as timeSpent
      FROM `pageViews` 
      WHERE `time_spent` > 0 
      GROUP BY `page_id`) myTable
JOIN pages ON pages.id = page_id 
ORDER BY timeSpent DESC 
LIMIT 5
```